# Does the Debian packaging system and RVM play well together?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, debian

**Update**

*Forgive my ignorance, I think I asked him about rvm when I really meant RubyGems. And I think he's thinking of RubyGems because there does seem to be some controversy over it, at least there was in the past: http://stakeventures.com/articles/2008/12/04/rubygem-is-from-mars-aptget-is-from-venus.  So please s/rvm/RubyGems/g for the below question.*

**End update**

My server admin is a little wary of using rvm on Debian. Here's what he says:

> Unfortunately, the whole rvm system doesn't interact properly with a
>   packaging system like Debian, and it's a nightmare to deploy when you
>   do the deployment at different times. [You can easily end up with
>   different versions of modules on different systems, etc, and you have
>   to deal with rvm stomping all over the Debian packaging system.]

I think what he's saying here is that we are going to be running the app across multiple servers and if we upgrade one server, it's going to cause serious problems for us.

Is there a way to address his concerns?

Comment: I don't really get his concerns. RVM stores all of your Rubies in `~/.rvm`, not in any of the `dpkg` managed `/usr` folders.

Comment: Please see my update. I think I screwed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubygems does not allows good control of gem versions, but together with bundler it allows a lot better control of version compared to apt-get.

You need to read on [Bundler](https://gembundler.com) - it allows you to specify loose dependencies in `Gemfile` and strict ones are recorded in `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Bundler looks like the solution. I am slightly familiar with it through my recent explorations of rails. I will definitely read up on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

RVM in no way shape or form 'stomps' on the debian package system. RVM installs either in $HOME/.rvm for a general user, or in /usr/local/rvm using the 'rvm' group to which members must be added which is the normal place for 3rd party non-mission-critical applications, headers, and libraries.

RVM came into existence *because* of package managers. They were forever screwing up dependencies of rubies and gems, being behind the times for getting security updates pushed out immediately, for multiple rubies to be installed and managed on the same box without having to play symlink games to get them to work, and made deployments to multiple machines with multiple disparate deployment requirements a nightmare.

RVM solved all of that in a more than fairly seamless matter, with a specific eye on ensuring not only security of the install, and the users that use it, but also to ensuring that the package manager was in no way involved. This ensures that the package management tools and their databases of installed packages wouldn't get suddenly wacked.

I got involved as a user, and then as a developer on the RVM Project *because* it solved the dilemma so well and so elegantly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe I asked the wrong question, though. Please see my update to this question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

His concerns are that **ruby is a moving target**, ruby is updated every few months and **all** users should always update to **latest patch level**.

Ruby is a lot different packages (maybe except openssl), where ruby team is updating releases with patches, this allows focusing security efforts in one place, but this is against **conservative** approach of package managers where a version is picked and only security patches are applied to it, as **stable** it sounds - it spreads security effort on multiple teams and slows down whole open source community. Operating system maintainers do not want to accept the fact someone does part of the work for them and they could trust someone with it.

As for the repetitiveness of the process your admin is showing a lot of ignorance, RVM allows to lock versions, which is against the the Ruby approach explained above. So the simplest way to lock everything is to lock RVM to one version:

```
rvm install 1.15.14
```

But if the locking of RVM is required the preferred way is to lock it to minor version where compatibility is kept, but updates are provided:

```
rvm install latest-1.15
```

RVM does not keep this versions going for a very long time, but anytime there are concerns about current stable "stability" - we keep the previous version updated so you can decide which one to use.

@deryldoucette also explained a lot in his answer, I tried to not "reexplain" things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe I asked the wrong question, though. Please see my update to this question.

Comment: He might as well not run Debian either, as its a moving target. You post a _2008_ article for an issue/concern in _2012_. 4 years later, the Ruby world has dramatically improved. Look at how long between stable releases, RubyGems updates security fixes & code fixes which your administrator can update (especially under RVM using gem update), provided the *Debian package maintainers* for the gems push updates out. Thats the only way to NOT step on the packages. If he does the ```gem update --system``` command on Debian to update installed system gems, Debian will respond you can't do that.

Comment: Ruby, with actual releases (not the trunk), moves far less than Debian does, so his concern is basically moot. If he downloads all the gems, and dependencies, he knows he needs and places them in a single shared directory, he can ```gem install ./*.gem```, or more sanely: ```for gem in $(ls *.gem); do gem install $name ; done``` to ensure all machines use the same versions. Also, by using Bundler and Gemfiles, he can ensure this by using the same Gemfile+Gemfile.lock across all machines. He needs to study a bit on how all this works. His fears can easily be allayed.